# How to return from a cell view to table view using swipe gestures

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I have a tableview which has 3 cells named a,b and c. When I click on 'a' it opens another view, now I want to swipe left to right so that it returns back to tableview. This is what I want to implement but I am unable to.

I have used touchesMoved method, it works if I only implement it on a simple view, but this is not working with UITableView.

Comment: Are you presenting the view modally? Please post the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` code that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to go is to attach a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the cell detail view, just before pushing it when a row is selected. This code would typically take place in your custom `UITableViewController` subclass.

```
// ...
    if(!myRecognizer) {
        myRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                        initWithTarget:self
                                action:@selector(popDetailView)];
        myRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    }
    if(!detailView) { ... }
    [detailView.view addGestureRecognizer:myRecongizer];
    ...
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
    [detailView release];
}

-(void)popDetailView {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // or NO

}
```

Comment: I have uploaded my project here: http://cl.ly/8a5g .Please look into the code and tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: i looked at your code, the solution i provided works, i attached a swipe recognizer to `fV.view`, and wrote a method that remove that it from its superview.